# How to wait for Monaco Editor validation to complete?

Tags: javascript, html, json, monaco-editor

In the monaco editor, I wanted to wait for the JSON validation to complete. If I used `onDidChangeModelContent`, the error information that the callback picked up by `getModelMarkers` is not up to date.
The editor may not complete the verification until 500 milliseconds later, and this time is uncertain.
And `onDidChangeModelDecorations` will trigger frequently, even will trigger the cursor changes.
Is there a way to get the JSON worker and I can await its validation?

Comment: Which json validation are you talking about ?

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided any code for us to test, but I go with a test scenario.

If you want the script to wait for the JSON validation to complete before taking further action, you should access JSON worker and then use the `Monaco.languages.json.jsonDefaults.getWorker()` method.

An example scenario could be crafted like this:

```js
const jsonWorker = await monaco.languages.json.jsonDefaults.getWorker();

const model = editor.getModel();

const validationResult = await jsonWorker.getSchemaValidation(model.uri.toString());

if (validationResult) {
  const markers = validationResult.markers;
}
```

Comment: TypeError: monaco.languages.json.jsonDefaults.getWorker is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Currently it doesn't seem possible to access the jsonWorker.

There is an open pull request for that feature: https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/pull/3956

But for your purpose this should be exactly what you are looking for:

```
  * Emitted when markers change for a model.
  * @event
  */
 export function onDidChangeMarkers(listener: (e: readonly Uri[]) => void): IDisposable;
```